# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Id',in SQL Server2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net

I am new to ADO.net and SQL Server 2005.

I created one table `TABLE1` with `id(pk),name,group` and I am trying to update using

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET name="stack" where id=2
```

then it giving bellow error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'Id'.

Answer (score 1):

You should use single quotes:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET name='stack' where id=2
```